# How do I change the API version of Simple Salesforce

Tags: simple-salesforce

I went to \simple_salesforce and changed a line in api.py by hand from

```
DEFAULT_API_VERSION = '42.0'
```

to

```
DEFAULT_API_VERSION = '51.0'
```

But it feels incorrect to do it like this. Is there some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's bit of text in [readme](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/blob/master/README.rst) in "additional features".

> SalesforceLogin, which takes in a username, password, security token,
> optional **version** and optional domain
>
> (...)
>
> SFType class, which is
> used internally by the **getattr**() method in the Salesforce() class
> and represents a specific SObject type. SFType requires object_name
> (i.e. Contact), session_id (an authentication ID), sf_instance
> (hostname of your Salesforce instance), and an optional **sf_version**

So looks like you can pass [`sf_version`](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/blob/master/simple_salesforce/login.py) to SalesforceLogin() call and it'll be respected. Or [`version`](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/blob/master/simple_salesforce/api.py) to Salesforce(). Check the files and experiment? Maybe even make a pull request in simple's Git repo so they update the default. 42 was over 3 years ago. It's perfectly fine to use newer API to see more tables, get some performance boost, bugfixes.